# Could someone check the edit processing code ? I think there's a bug in it?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463140/for-equation-equation-be-bmod-m-x-if-all-values-except-exponent-e-are-k) post gave me trouble, I edited it, tapped the +2 for editing after page refreshing (I do that too much), played around putting my mobile browser into desktop site mode (another thing I do too much of). It reloaded to the page not found warning. Getting out of Desktop mode, didn't fix it. I could still find the post through tags I remembered though (ruling out deletion).  I think between this anomaly, and the other post edit mishaps, someone needs to trace ( Settings in Chrome) the issue. It may be in code that gets initiated to signal editting changes. I can't unless I'm on a library computer, or get a gzip app, because the file given back is gzip format from the trace.

Comment: Heads up, I got it on changing to desktop mode again.This time, on this meta question.

Comment: I've been having trouble viewing comments, for several hours now, even after rebooting Windows and restarting Firefox. I haven't had any problem editing posts. Whatever the problem is this evening, it's one I've never seen before. (I'm only guessing that it is related to the trouble you have been having.) Not only my own comments are affected. MathJax is missing, from all or most of the comments I've looked at, and quite a lot of English text is missing as well.

Comment: Well there was the meta post about CSS as well. So who knows.